# JavaScript Drilldown Datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, datepicker

Is anyone aware of a Javascript datepicker which will allow you to drill-down to a given day from a certain decade ? For example, initially the calendar would show only decades, then the years when a decade is selected, then the months, etc... If I recall correctly, Windows 7 / Vista has a similar system to this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like I'll be modifying [Bootstrap Datepicker](https://github.com/eternicode/bootstrap-datepicker) to do this.